# Active Admin: how to set filter label dynamically

Tags: activeadmin

I tried this:

```
filter :something, :label => lambda{ condition?(current_active_admin_user) ? "option1" : "option2" }
```

but it does not work. But the same lambda code works for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if current_active_admin_user
   filter :something, :label => "option1" 
else
   filter :something, :label => "option2"
end
```

Good luck.

Comment: humm... going to give this a try next week. I had to resort to do the toggling in JS but if this works, it would clean things up.